# How to read QVector with QDataStream using PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qvector, qdatastream

I have a QtDataStream:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore

infile = QtCore.QFile(path)
if not infile.open(QtCore.QIODevice.ReadOnly):
   raise IOError(infile.errorString()
stream = QtCore.QDataStream(infile)
```

And I need to read a QVector.
I need something like this:

```
var = QtCore.Qvector()
stream >> var
```

But it seems that QVector class does not exist in PyQt5. Any ideas?

Comment: My idea is that a list in Python has the same purpose as a QVector.

Comment: How was that file generated?

Answer (score 2):

PyQt cannot wrap [QVector](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector.html), because it is a template class. Such classes are part of the C++ language, and have no equivalent in Python. To work around this limitation, PyQt has added some special wrapper methods to the QDataStream class which provide the same functionality in a different way.

These methods are [only mentioned in the PyQt documentation](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/api/qtcore/qdatastream.html#) - so this is one of those rare cases where you ***must*** consult the PyQt docs rather than the Qt ones. The special wrapper methods are all named using the format `read/write[TypeName]`, and include `readQVariantList` and `writeQVariantList` for reading and writing lists from a datastream:

```
>>> from PyQt5 import QtCore
>>> f = QtCore.QFile('test.dat')
>>> f.open(QtCore.QIODevice.ReadWrite)
True
>>> stream = QtCore.QDataStream(f)
>>> x = [3.142, 'foo', 7, QtCore.QPoint(3, 5), QtCore.QDate.currentDate()]
>>> stream.writeQVariantList(x)
>>> f.seek(0)
True
>>> stream.readQVariantList()
[3.142, 'foo', 7, PyQt5.QtCore.QPoint(3, 5), PyQt5.QtCore.QDate(2023, 4, 6)]
```

In addition to this, there is an alternative, lower level way to read data from template classes like QVector and QList, which involves reading the length of the container first and then reading each element one-by-one (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40750614/984421) for more details). But this will still only result in a Python list - there's no way to create an instance of QVector or QList in PyQt (and there's never any need to do so).

Comment: Yes ekhmuro. But as you said PyQt has wrappres. But I don not find the wrapper for QVector

Comment: @Juan You do not need QVector at all. You ***must*** use the methods shown in my answer. There is no other possible solution. PyQt provides those methods because it cannot wrap QVector (which is a template class, and therefore only available in C++).

Comment: @juan I have updated my answer with more details showing how things work in PyQt.